# JSON.parse(e.data) - websocket's onmessage - ReferenceError: e is not defined / 'data' of undefined / WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

websocket/JSON newbie here. I have an issue with receiving data from function event. Could somebody help me?

Looks like the message is send properly to the server (correct message_cart value while using sendMessage() function), but issues while receiving data.

**My console:**

> websocket.min.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of
>   undefined
>       at receiveMessage (websocket.min.js:35)
>
> message from cart to server: 10 // the number is correct
>
> websocket.min.js:83 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

**My websocket.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  'use strict';

  var ws_protocol = 'ws://';
  if (window.location.protocol == "https:")
    ws_protocol = 'wss://';
  var ws_url = ws_protocol + window.location.host + '/ws/auctions/' + qs;
  var webSocket = new WebSocket(ws_url);

  var amountbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('amountButton');
  var message_cart;

  webSocket.onopen = sendMessage();
  webSocket.onmessage = receiveMessage();

  function receiveMessage(e) {
    var msgData = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if ('auction_data' in msgData) {
        console.log("here we are, 'auction_data' in msgData");
    } else if ('cart_data' in msgData) {
        console.log("here we are, 'cart_data' in msgData");
    }
  };

  function sendMessage() {

    for(let i = 0; i < amountbutton.length; i++) {

      amountbutton[i].onclick = (e) => {
        if(!amountbutton[i].nextElementSibling) {
          message_cart = amountbutton[i].previousElementSibling.value;
          message_cart++;
        } else {
          message_cart = amountbutton[i].nextElementSibling.value;
          message_cart--;
        }
        console.log("message from cart to server: " + message_cart);
        webSocket.send(message_cart);
      }
    }
  }

  webSocket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.error('Websocket closed.');
  };

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for web socket to call your `onopen` and `onmessage` callbacks, you **must** assign them to listeners as *a function*, not as *values* these function are returning. So the solution is to just assign these functions without calling them, like that:

```
  webSocket.onopen = sendMessage; // <- no curly braces in there
  webSocket.onmessage = receiveMessage; // <- no curly braces in there
```

Hope it helps :)